# How to pick specific commits and pushed those into another branch?

Tags: git

**TL;DR**

Can I push into our UAT branch just the changes I made (ie changes made to code3 and code4) without touching the changes made by developer1 (code1, code2 and my-js.js)?

---

I think my situation is best to explain with an example.

The developers normally work on the dev branch which contains 7 files.

```
code1.php
code2.php
code3.php
code4.php
code5.php
my-js.js
my-css.css
```

There are 3 developers in the project.

```
developer1 = able to push new branches but not able to merge into any branch
developer2 = same access as developer1
developer3 = me. I have admin access to the repository. If developer1 and 2 needs to merge changes to the dev branch, they send it my way for approval
```

A new issue came up and this was assigned to developer1. Developer1 git pulled on the remote dev branch to get the latest code. And he then created a new local branch called "jira-ticket1" and made changes to files code1 and code2. He also made changes to my-js.js

Another issue came up (jira-ticket2) and this was assigned to developer2. He also git pulled on the remote dev branch and then created a new local branch called "jira-ticket2" and made changes to code5.

At the end of the day, only developer1 has finished. He pushed his new branch into our remote repository and then created a pull request for me to approved. I approved the pull request 5 minutes after receiving it.

The following morning, something urgent (jira-ticket3) came up and this was assigned to me. This ticket requires me to make changes to code3 and code4. I also did a git pull before starting work (thus picking up the changes made by develop1). I also created a new branch and then pushed and approved my changes once I'm done.

Because of the urgency of the issue, the tester was only able to test my changes and he has approved it to go to our UAT branch

**Now my question**

Can I push into our UAT branch just the changes I made (ie changes made to code3 and code4) without touching the changes made by developer1?

The only branches normally showing on my local repository are the dev and my own branches.

ps. I've read several "similar" questions but I'm unsure if this applies to my situation.

Comment: Can you make a tl;dr version of this? If you want to pick specific commit's, I've an answer for that

Comment: The common way we handle this is a ticket branch, that will be merged in later - is that not a good solution? Branch out to before commit 1.

Comment: @Mr.Alien just did. Thanks!

Comment: @kabanus can you please explain a ticket branch? when I approved the commit done by developer1, I have no way of knowing I'll be getting an urgent request unrelated to jira-ticket1.

Comment: Still am confused, but I think what you are looking for is `git cherry-pick YOUR_COMMIT_ID`, this will help you pick only specific commits to your master branch. Let me know if this is what you were looking for. Not posting as an answer as am not sure about your requirements.

Comment: @Mr.Alien can you please explain that with actual commands? Only dev and my own branches are in the local repository. UAT often stays remotely.

Comment: @mrjayviper Say you have two branches, master, and branch1, now you committed multiple commits in master and you want to pick only specific commit, you can checkout to master branch first, then use `git cherry-pick HASH_ID_OF_BRANCH1_COMMIT`, this will pick only specific commit of branch1 and will put it into the master branch. Hope you understood.

Answer (score 1):

The way we handle this is a ticket branch. Suppose the original tree was:

```
A-B
```

After the pull request you would have

```
A-B-C
```

with C containing the changes (it's easier to discuss commits rather than files with git.) Now something urgent comes up, and you can't use the C code for it. Checkout B (using the hash or HEAD~1), branch out, and commit your fix:

```
A-B-C  <-Master
   -D  <-Ticket branch
```

Now you're fine, and the history will show that you guys had to split for a while. Once things settle, just merge back:

```
A-B-C---E
    -D-/
```

Of course, you could change the pull request to sit on master, then on master

```
git reset --hard <hash of B commit>
```

In this picture you have:

```
A-B-C <- Some temp branch
   -D <-Master now
```

Commit your file, push the master branch, and then merge/rebase C into master.

===========================

A clarification on the code using the second method. After the pull you have:

```
A-B-C <-UAT
```

Now,

```
git checkout -b tempbranch #to save C
git checkout master
git reset --hard HEAD~1 #Or explicitly B hash
```

Now the tree is:

```
A-B(<-UAT)-C <- tempbranch
```

MAke your changes and

```
git commit -a -m"My changes"
```

Tree:

```
A-B-C <-tempbranch
   \
     D<-UAT
```

Now you can push it. When you want to include C, either rebase it or merge it. For a rebase:

```
git checkout tempbranch
git rebase UAT
git checkout master
git merge tempbranch
git branch -D tempbranch #Not needed!
```

Now you have:

```
A-B-D-C
```

Push.

Comment: hi again. we use a branch called UAT for UAT testing. how do I merge just my commits (D in your example) to this UAT branch? the way our auto compiler is setup, it always picks up the UAT branch.

Comment: I showed a rebase solution. You can merge as well, if you already pushed `C`, that would be safer.

Comment: seems this will only work if I git pulled "B"? What if developer1 gets another task and he didn't know to git pull but just get the latest?

Comment: In my picture everyone starts with A and B. You will have to pull C eventually since it's already available to everyone I would suggest committing your fix to the temp (bug fix) branch rather then master, and then pushing the merge  later.